# Deklination eines Adjektivs zwischen Zahlwort und Nomen

Tags: grammar, adjective, declension, adjective-ending

Wenn in einem Satz die Rede von sämtlichen Dingen (plural) ist und zwischen sämtliche und dem Nomen ein Adjektiv ist: Endet dieses auf -en oder auf -e?

**Beispiel:**

Heisst es

> XY erfüllt sämtliche fachliche Anforderungen.

oder

> XY erfüllt sämtliche fachlichen Anforderungen.

---

Im Grunde heisst es ja

> die fachlichen Anforderungen

Auch wenn man den Satz mit "alle" anstelle von "sämtliche" bildet, heisst es klar:

> XY erfüllt alle fachlichen Anforderungen.

Jedoch hört sich *sämtliche fachlichen Anforderungen* für mich einfach falsch an.

Was wäre korrekt und wie lauten die Regeln dazu?

Comment: Related: [Adjective declension in “Wir haben große Fernseher”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/4928/1224)

Comment: Hinweis: [Diese Antwort](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/4929/1224) zu der verwandten Frage, kann ohne Weiteres auch auf diese Frage übernommen werden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ein Blick in den [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/saemtlich) enthüllt die folgenden Beispiele:

> - (attributiv): sämtliches Brauchbare
> - sämtlicher aufgehäufte Sand
> - die Nutzung sämtlicher vorhandenen Energie
> - mit sämtlichem verfügbaren Material
> - sämtliches beschlagnahmte Eigentum
> - sämtliche Beamten/(auch:) Beamte
> - sämtliche anwesenden/(seltener auch:) anwesende Bürger
> - die Kleidung sämtlicher Gefangener/(seltener auch:) Gefangenen
> - anhand sämtlicher vorhandener/(seltener auch:) vorhandenen Bücher
> - (allein stehend): ob ich seine Bücher kenne? Ich habe sämtliche gelesen
> - (adverbial): seine Romane sind sämtlich autobiografisch

In Deinem Fall passen beide Endungen, aber ohne "n" (also nur "-e") kommt seltener vor als mit "n" (sprich "-en").

Comment: Der Dudeneintrag hat sich Stand 15.7.16  geändert und enthält nun in fast allen Beispielen zwei mögliche Formen, z. B. auch *sämtlicher aufgehäufte**r** Sand* oder *die Nutzung sämtlicher vorhandene**r** Energie*. Diese (neuen?) Formen entsprechen eher meinem Sprachgefühl als die o. g., allerdings sehe ich mich außerstande da irgendwelche Regeln abzuleiten, wann welche Endungen verwendet werden.