# Adjective declension in "Wir haben große Fernseher"

Tags: grammar, declension, adjective-ending

I just started to learn German declension. According to [that site](http://german.about.com/library/weekly/aa033098.htm) an adjective should end in '-en' for plural nouns. But I also [found this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_declension#Strong_inflection.5B6.5D.5B7.5D) which says that attributive adjectives should 'decline strongly'.

My question is: is this the case at hand? Can you provide some explanation and rules of thumb?

Comment: Related: [Deklination eines Adjektivs zwischen Zahlwort und Nomen](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/3910/1224)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [table on this Wikipedia page](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Starke_Deklination_der_Adjektive) which summarizes how to decline German adjectives.

There are two kinds of forms:

- weak: **-en**
- strong: **-e**

Example:

> Die großen Fernseher stehen hinten.

but

> Große Fernseher sind teuer.

**Rules**

From the Wikipedia article

> Das Adjektiv wird „schwach“ dekliniert, wenn es einem Artikel oder Pronomen in nicht endungsloser Form folgt: *der grüne Tee, hier ist dieser grüne und dort ist jener schwarze.*
>
> Dies gilt auch für nicht endungslose Artikel, die mit einer Präposition verschmolzen sind: *im Weißen Haus, zur alten Mühle, unterm grünen Baum*
>
> Als endungslose Artikel- und Pronomenformen gelten *dein, ein, ihr, kein, mein* und *sein* sowie undeklinierte Indefinitpronomina wie *manch* oder *etwas*.
>
> Ausnahme: Nach manchen deklinierten Indefinitpronomen kann auch ein stark dekliniertes Adjektiv stehen: *irgendwelche schönen Dinge* (schwach), alternativ: *irgendwelche schöne Dinge* (stark); *mancher klugen Leute* (schwach), alternativ: *mancher kluger Leute* (stark)
> Ansonsten wird das Adjektiv „stark“ dekliniert: *grüner Tee, hier ist ein grüner und dort ist etwas schwarzer*

Comment: Thanks splattne. It seems that the about.com tutorial lists the cases for weak inflection, without warning the readers that there are also strong and mixed inflections :( One more thing: how can I infer that 'Fernseher' is a plural noun?

Comment: @Covi, from the inflection: Die großen Fernseher - Der große Fernseher; mehrere große Fernseher - ein großer Fernseher (and the article in my examples ;)

Comment: @Covi *große Fernseher* can only be plural, because the singular form always has a definite or indefinite article (like in English): "Wir haben einen großen Fernseher" / "Wir reparieren den großen Fernseher." etc.

Comment: @splattne: Well, strictly speaking, that is not entirely correct. The singular "großer Fernseher" (i.e. without an article) would be grammatically valid, but then again, the adjective would have a different ending, and it is stylistically really weird with a word like "Fernseher":

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Why weird? Example, customer asks salesperson: "Haben Sie große Fernseher? Ich brauche einen sehr großen Fernseher für mein Restaurant." - "Ja, wir haben große Fernseher."

Comment: @splattne: I was talking about the *singular* without an article.

Answer (score -1):

**Singular (Einzahl)**

Nominativ Singular (erster Fall Einzahl):

> Da drüben steht der große Fernseher.
>   Der große Fernseher ist teuer.

Genitiv Singular (zweiter Fall Einzahl):

> Das ist der Preis des großen Fernsehers.
>   Ich bewundere die Farben des großen Fernsehers.

Dativ Singular (dritter Fall Einzahl):

> Diese Schachtel gehört zu dem großen Fernseher.
>   Die Schuld an dieser Misere muss man dem großen Fernseher geben.

Akkusativ Singular (vierter Fall Einzahl):

> Ich sehe den großen Fernseher.
>   Hans hat den großen Fernseher abtransportiert.

---

**Plural (Mehrzahl)**

Nominativ Plural (erster Fall Mehrzahl):

> Da drüben stehen die großen Fernseher.
>   Die großen Fernseher sind teuer.

Genitiv Plural (zweiter Fall Mehrzahl):

> Das sind die Preise der großen Fernseher.
>   Ich bewundere die Farben der großen Fernseher.

Dativ Plural (dritter Fall Mehrzahl):

> Diese Schachteln gehören zu den großen Fernsehern.
>   Die Schuld an dieser Misere muss man den großen Fernsehern geben.

Akkusativ Plural (vierter Fall Mehrzahl):

> Ich sehe die großen Fernseher.
>   Hans hat die großen Fernseher abtransportiert.

Comment: Leider deckt deine Antwort aber nicht "Wir haben große Fernseher" ab. Z.B. "Große Fernseher sind teuer", "Ich bewundere die Farben großer Fernseher", "Die Schuld an dieser Misere muss man großen Fernsehern geben", "Hans hat große Fernseher abtransportiert"